# after installing BAM , wso2 publisher is not opening

Tags: api, wso2-bam

after installing **Business Activity Monitor** wso2 publisher is not opening. An error occurred i.e

```
"HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

type Status report

message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.34"
```

Comment: What is yout API Manager Version?

Comment: version  2.5.0 , Please give me the solution

Comment: We don't have 2.5.0 version in API Manager. What do you mean by `wso2 publisher`?

Comment: yes.. now what can i do? give me solution

Comment: This question is very ambiguous. i guess 2.5.0 refers to the BAM version. Now, what's your API manager version? when does this error appear/what were you trying to do? need a better explanation in the question if you expect a solution.

Comment: I am  installed  wso2 api manager at my local machine , then i publish API using publisher of this application , But when I installed wso2bam-2.5.0 , i can't access publisher , API store .. It displaying error

Comment: https://<hostname>:9443/publisher not working after installed BAM

Comment: did you configure a port offset? do you see any errors in API manager console when it starts up?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a port conflict issue. If you haven't set a port offset, set it in `<BAM>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` as in [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM250/Port+Offset). Otherwise both the servers try to run on the same ports and results in conflicts. Also when you access bam console or publish data, use the correct ports with offset.

Answer (score 0):

After R & D solved error , I change port offset of /repository/conf/carbon.xml 
API manager & BAM should be not be run at same port

Port set rule

```
Ports offset. This entry will set the value of the ports defined below to
         the define value + Offset.
         e.g. Offset=2 and HTTPS port=9443 will set the effective HTTPS port to 9445
```